# Python pow operation withouth math import

Tags: math, pow

My Python script uses the pow operation. During a tidy up some days ago, I removed the import math. I've just realised my pow operation is still working.

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I get it. Python has a builtin pow function which works slightly differently to the math.pow one. It accepts an optional third parameter which causes it to return the modulo of the third parameter.

I was never using the math library version at all. I should have realised because I had never used the dot notation to get to the function!